# How can I correctly create my local repository based on existing folders?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to create a repository local to my machine. I have TortoiseSVN 1.9.5.
I have 2 directories I want included, Test and Live. I would like them in one repository. 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Test\
C:\Users\user\Documents\Live\
There are other files in the Documents folder that will not be a part of this.

I also do not want the svn information within the Test and Live folders if possible, can it be put in a different folder?

I have tried to create a repository and this is what I ended up with:
I had a svn directory in C:\Users\user\Documents (contains db, conf, hooks, locks, format, README.txt, and svn.ico) and in C:\Users\user\Documents\Test\ I had folders relating to svn (I have since gotten rid of them). What I did to create this in svn, was to right click on my Test folder and click Import under svn commands. At the time, the URL of the repository was file:///C:/Users/allisonc/Documents/svn/, but looking at the repobrowser, it had the folders and files just in there and they needed to be in a subfolder. I tried to create a subfolder and move the items but when I went to commit them I got an error since it could now longer find those files in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a repository](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-create-tortoisesvn) somewhere like `C:\SVNRepo\FOO`, but don't create the branch, tag und trunk structure that TSVN offers you. Open the repository browser and create the 2 folders `LIVE` and `TEST`.

Now [checkout](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html) both folders from URL `file:///C:/SVNRepo/FOO/Live` and `file:///C:/SVNRepo/FOO/Test` to `C:\Users\user\Documents\Live\` and `C:\Users\user\Documents\Test\`

Now copy your data to the folders, [add them](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-add.html) and [commit the data](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html).